# iMessage speech (applescript) timing out after upgrade to yosemite

Tags: macos, applescript, upgrade, messages

When I receive an iMessage, chat or Message on my desktop (iMac), it is read out loud.

After the upgrade to Yosemite it does not work. I continue to receive the message that "AppleScript timed out." I click on "wait" and it will read it. This occurs when I SEND as well as when I RECEIVE messages, although reading aloud is only on receive. - I would love if someone might address this issue! It still works great on my previous OS version on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

**I originally wrote:**

This bug appears to be resolved in 10.10.2

****I was *wrong* ****

For me, the bogus timeout alerts seem to take longer to start after enabling a handler script than they did in 10.10.1, but they still happen and make the AppleScript handler feature unusable. By loading up my handler script with debugging code (logging everything) and tracing Messages with DTrace, I've nailed down beyond a doubt that the timeout alert is triggered for every event passed to the script within milliseconds of the event before the script itself is in control, blocking its execution.

Comment: I upgraded and it still times out intermittently - I see that the editor was not changed in applescript because it still had last week's dates on them- Grrrr.

Answer (score -1):

This was resolved for me in El Capitan

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please avoid posting non-answer content into the **"Answer"** section as it is only for answers. Express yourself through upvotes if something was helpful for you

Comment: You are lucky -- I just upgraded and now i get a Messages that loads and then gets stuck -- it won't do anything. Al least before it would work (without speech!). Thanks.